# Prove that a 'close' pair exists in a group of 100 people

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose there are 100 people. Some know each other and some do not.

Let us call a pair of people **close** if there exists a group of at least 50 people (excluding the pair itself) such that everyone in this group knows either **both** people in the pair or **none** of them.

> Prove that a close pair exists.

**Edits**

1. Knowledge of self does not count
2. All connections are mutual (Alice knows Bob means Bob knows Alice)
3. The group of 50 does not include the pair itself

Comment: Does a person count as knowing himself?

Comment: And can Alice know Bob without Bob knowing Alice (or vice versa)?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good questions. Updated my problem

Comment: Hmm, actually a better question than self-knowledge might be: Can the 50 people include one or both of the two I claim are "close"?

Comment: fixed that as well

Comment: In other words it is claimed that, if each edge of the complete graph $K_{100}$ is colored red or blue, then there are two vertices $u,v$ with at least $50$ monochromatic paths of length $2$ from $u$ to $v.$ If you change "at least $50$" to "at least $49$" I see how to do this with a simple counting argument. I guess something more clever is needed to get $50.$. What is the source of this puzzle?

Comment: @bof: Or, in other words, $K_{2,50}$ embeds monochromatically into the edge-colored graph.

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, each path is monochchromatic, but some are red and some blue.

Comment: @bof: Ah! That's an interpretation of the task that hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The wording "everyone in this group knows either both people in the pair or none of them" seems to clearly imply that some members of the group may know both people in the pair while others know neither of them. Anyway, the statement OP wants to prove is false under your strong interpretation. Consider the random graph: the presence of each edge is decided by an independent fair coin toss. The probability that there is a pair with 50 common acquaintances or 50 common non-acquaintances is (rough back of the envelope estimate) less than 1%. Did I do that calculation wrong?

Comment: @bof: "either"/"or" distributes weirdly in natural language, so I initially read it as "either [everyone in this group knows both people] or [everyone in this group knows none of them]".

Comment: @bof Thanks for your solution. The source is a Russian data science school (link in Russian: https://efiminem.github.io/supershad/09-06-2018/)

Comment: @HenningMakholm this is exactly how I read this question in the exam as well. The wording is tricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a partial answer, as it proves a weaker statement with $50$ replaced by $49.$ First let me restate the problem in a less confusing, more straightforward form:

> Suppose each edge of the complete graph $K_{100}$ is colored red or blue. Show that there are two vertices which are connected by at least $50$ monochromatic paths of length $2.$

I don't know how to prove that, but a simple counting argument proves the following:

**Proposition.** If each edge of the complete graph $K_{99}$ is colored red or blue, then there are two vertices which are connected by at least $49$ monochromatic paths of length $2.$

**Proof.** Let $V$ be the vertex set of $K_{99}.$ Let $p$ be the number of monochromatic paths of length $2.$ For $v\in V$ let $p_v$ be the number of monochromatic paths of length $2$ with midpoint $v.$ For $u,v\in V,u\ne v,$ let $m_{u,v}$ be the number of monochromatic paths of length $2$ from $u$ to $v.$ Let $m=\max\{m_{u,v}:u,v\in V,u\ne v\}.$

On the one hand, clearly, we have
$$p\le\binom{99}2m.\tag1$$
Now the minimum possible value of $p_v$ is $2\binom{49}2,$ attained only if $v$ is incident with $49$ red edges and $49$ blue edges. Moreover, it is not possible for this minimum to be attained by all $v$ simultaneously, as the subgraph consisting of the red edges would then be a $49$-regular graph on $99$ vertices. Thus we have
$$p=\sum_{v\in V}p_v\gt99\cdot2\binom{49}2.\tag2$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$m\gt\frac{99\cdot2\binom{49}2}{\binom{99}2}=48,$$
whence $m\ge49.$

**Remark.** The same argument shows that, if each edge of the complete graph $K_{4t-1}$ is colored red or blue, then there are two vertices which are connected by at least $2t-1$ monochromatic paths.